How to exclude line with join
I have a file from which I want to exclude some lines regarding some criteria.
I have identified them with this query:
SELECT *
FROM ab.Price_table
INNER JOIN bib.items
    ON xxetab = zzetab AND xxitem = zzitem
inner JOIN bib2.spefile 
    ON zzcod = spcod AND xxdat = spdat AND xxdev = spdev AND spflg = 'INFO'
WHERE xxpri IN (spPRR1, psPRR2, psPRR3, psPRR4, psPRR5);

this returns me 1 lines.
I want to have all the data from my ab.Price_table without including the line retuned previously
I tried a left join but it's not working

not in perhaps?

Please add an example of a data tables and an expected result.

You can use 'not in' or 'not exist'.
SELECT * FROM ab.Price_table pt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM ab.Price_table inner_pt
INNER JOIN bib.items bi on inner_pt.xxetab = bi.zzetab and inner_pt.xxitem = bi.zzitem
INNER JOIN bib2.spefile bs on bi.zzcod = bs.spcod and inner_pt.xxdat = bs.spdat and inner_pt.xxdev = bs.spdev and bs.spflg = 'INFO'
WHERE inner_pt.xxpri IN (bs.spPRR1, bs.psPRR2, bs.psPRR3, bs.psPRR4, bs.psPRR5)
AND pt.xxetab = inner_pt.xxetab 
AND pt.xxitem = inner_pt.xxitem
AND pt.xxdat = inner_pt.xxdat
AND pt.xxdev = inner_pt.xxdev
);


SELECT *
FROM ab.Price_table
INNER JOIN bib.items
    ON xxetab = zzetab AND xxitem = zzitem
inner JOIN bib2.spefile 
    ON zzcod = spcod AND xxdat = spdat AND xxdev = spdev AND spflg = 'INFO'
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM ab.Price_table
INNER JOIN bib.items
    ON xxetab = zzetab AND xxitem = zzitem
inner JOIN bib2.spefile 
    ON zzcod = spcod AND xxdat = spdat AND xxdev = spdev AND spflg = 'INFO'
WHERE xxpri IN (spPRR1, psPRR2, psPRR3, psPRR4, psPRR5);

